# Removing Characters from a File

Tags: c++, filestream

How can arbitrary characters be removed (not replaced by something) in a file?

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream FileStream("MyFile.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
    // For the sake of argument, MyFile.txt already has stuff in it.

    FileStream.seekg(5);
    FileStream.remove(); // Something like this.
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about files that fit in memory, or really large ones?

Comment: @Space They're potentially large, but not too big.  I understand that I can store the characters temporarily in some sort of container and then overwrite the file, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: File systems (most common) are not designed to be efficient with regards to removing small chunks from files. C++ generalizes files to a stream so there is no efficient way there. You may find some OS specific facilities that allow you to manipulate the file sectors directly (efficient but non portable and significantly harder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Read the entire file in the memory, then save it to the file excluding unwanted parts.
2. Copy the source file to newly created file excluding unwanted parts, remove the source file, then rename second file.