# How to remove last character in text file C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file into which I write first 10 characters the user inputs:

```
int x=0;
ofstream fout("out.txt"); 
while (x<=10)
{
   char c=getch();
   if (c==8)//check for backspace
      fout<<'\b';
   else
      fout<<c;
   x++;
}
```

Whenever the user presses backspace I want to delete the previously entered character from the text file.

I tried writing `'\b'` to the file but it doesn't delete the last character.

How can I do so?

Thanks

Comment: One option would be to use seekg or seekp (Random file I/O operators) to move the pointer and then write a blank space. However, this is really crude and I believe something better should exist.

Comment: @therainmaker i tried that too but it doesnt work

Comment: A cleaner way to do this would be to keep the data until your are "done", and *then* write it to a file. The other way would be to read the entire file, then write everything but the last character.

Comment: @crashmstr i have used 10 as an example, the actual program runs infinite number of times until the user stops it

Comment: @tobi303 each character is 1 byte so I should shift the filepointer by 1 each time the user presses back space am I right?

Comment: @user4748321 : Are you sure you are doing it correctly? Because I have overwritten files in the past by moving the pointer. To confirm, you are writing `" "` after shifting, right?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php

Comment: @KarolyHorvath is it there for c++ too?

Comment: oops wrong link. obviously. google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ delete last character in a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529027/c-delete-last-character-in-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, your requirement is that a BS should move the file pointer one position back. That's just what `seekp` is done for.

In windows (because of getch...) the following just meet the requirement:

```
int x=0;
ofstream fout("out.txt"); 
while (x<=10)
{
    char c=getch();
    if (c==8) { //check for backspace
        fout.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::end);
        if (x > 0) x -= 1; // ensure to get 10 characters at the end
    }
    else {
        fout<<c;
        x++;
    }
}   return 0;
```

It works here **because the last character is overwritten**. Unfortunately, as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2261635) confirms, there is no standard way to truncate an open file with `fstream`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way by which you can delete the last character of the file in C++. You have to go the trivial way ie :-

```
Read the contents of the file except the last one & copy it to another file
```

You can either use `input-output iterators` or `strings` or `both` for the same.

Comment: Not true. There are quite a number of ways to shorten an existing file.

Comment: @RobK Do elaborate on what you said