# Overwritte last char in file

Tags: c++

I wanted to remove the last char in file and

- Not writing a new file and rename it

Because the file will grow larger over time (From a 1 byte file to 1 GB file, increase by 1 byte over time (1000000000 rewrites cycle)) and the rewrite will damage the hard disk

Comment: I don't think there's a different way in c++. I don't know how Unix operator `>>` works, but assuming you're on a Unix system you could do `echo "<your_char>" >> "filename` with `system` in c++. `>>` will append the char to the file, but I don't know if it rewrites it to be honest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529027/c-delete-last-character-in-a-txt-file

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp

Comment: @VinayakSingla Are copy file data and trunc file and then write the same data to the file damage the hard disk or not?

Comment: [truncate(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) (Unix/Linux-specific)

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky OMG thanks, you saved me a ton of time! <3

Comment: Editing the title to end in "closed" is NOT the way to close a question. Please either delete the question, or make a suitable answer, or indicate the duplicate question.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Please make an anwer from your comment, so that this a) becomes a Q/A instead of a Q/comment   b) gets out of the list of unanswered questions. Sadly, this does not really otherwise qualify for a close-vote.

Comment: @Yunnosch Idk how to choose comment as answer so I said "closed" because this may be helpful to other people

Comment: You cannot choose a commen as an answer, that is why I often ask people to make their answering comment into a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

[en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp](http://%20%09%20en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)