# Deleting character from file at the current position of the file object

Tags: c++, fstream

Please look at this minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("asd.txt", ios_base::out);

    file << "this is a sentence!" << endl;

    ///is it possible at this point to delete the last character, the exclamation mark, from the file asd.txt using the object "file"?

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a sentence to a file `asd.txt` using a file object `file`. Is it possible to delete the character `!` from `asd.txt` using `file`?

Comment: This would be possible in C++17 using resize_file http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file otherwise I belive you have to just 'overwrite' the part you don't want or rewrite the file alltogether. Other solutions might involve OS specific API.

Comment: Otherwise the way would be to read all the data to the string, pop the last char, open clean file with the same name and write into it. Issue comes with large files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Characters from a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503863/removing-characters-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::ofstream` with `seekp` and `write` to overwrite the ! with a space ( I tried just deleting the ! or replacing it by '\0' but i can't seem to get that to work )
    #include 
    #include

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("asd.txt");
    ///is it possible at this point to delete the last character, the exclamation mark, from the file asd.txt using the object "file"?
    //Yes!
    file.write("this is a sentence!", 19); // writes 19 chars to the file
    long pos = file.tellp(); // gets the current position of the buffer ( in this case 19)
    file.seekp(pos - 1); // subtracts one from the buffer position ( now 18 )
    // writes a space that is one char at the current position of the file ( 18, which overwrites the '!' that is in pos 19)
    file.write("", 1); 
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

There are many alternatives though, you can always just close the file, reopen the file with `std::ios_base::trunc` which will clear all the content in the file, Then you can write the string again only up until before the `!`

`file.write("this is a sentence!", 18);`

You can also store the string in a std::string and call std::string::pop_back() to remove the last character and then write that into the file after clearing the file contents. Just store the stream into a `std::ostringstream` and get the `string` from the `ostringstream` and then `pop_back()` the `!`.

It really depends on your use case, if you want to give more detail I'd be free to help you out a little more.